# Plot graph using Pandas - Plot 3 column data in a graph

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have data in my dataframe as  `df` with 3 columns (CODE, AGE, COUNT)

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'CODE': ['A', 'B', 'N', 'k', 'A', 'A', 'Z', 'L', 'O', 'B', 'Z'],
        'AGE': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 40, 42, 48, 65, 65],
        'COUNT': [1800, 4000, 2000, 6500, 3500, 5000, 4, 10, 10, 8, 8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I need to plot the data as a bar chart with the AGE in X axis and COUNT in Y axis. Also needed to mark the code such as A,B,N,Z etc. on top of each bar in the diagram. How can we mention the CODE across each bar in pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want something like this:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(x='AGE', y='COUNT', logy=True)
for n, i in enumerate(ax.patches):
     ax.annotate(df.iloc[n, df.columns.get_loc('CODE')], (i.get_x() + i.get_width() / 2., i.get_height()),
     ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='black', xytext=(0, 5),
     textcoords='offset points')
#Make space for labels
_ = ax.set_ylim(0, df['COUNT'].max()+10000)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @FayasKY did this solution help you?